# Editing then combining large number of CSV in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, csv, sed, terminal, cat

I have a folder of ~8400 CSV files that are large:

- 2 columns
- ~17k lines

I tired just merging it all in Terminal with cat, and got a 3.2 GB CSV file that Excel just laughed at when I tried to import. So I need to get these smaller before I merge them so I can start messing with the data in Excel. Fortunately, I need only a small subset of the data.

Basically, it is an hourly time-series going back to Jan 2018 (first column is date/time), but I only need the end-of-day number for the last 90 days

- Extract the last ~2160 lines of each CSV (90*24)
- I also need a delimiter to show me where each table begins once merged, so after extracting the last ~2160 lines, I want to insert in a line at the beginning of each with the filename without extension.
- Delete all but the last record of each day.

By my math, this leaves me with under 800k lines, which Excel should be able to open.

I was thinking sed could do all this, then cat to merge the new edited files, but it’s way beyond my abilities. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extremely simplified version that you can extrapolate from.

I have five files in my directory:

```
$ ls folder-with-files/
a   b   c   d   e
```

Each file has five rows.

```
$ cat folder-with-files/a
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat folder-with-files/b
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

etc.

Now let's say I want the last two lines of each file. The key there is the `tail` command. Before that I'll echo out the file name according to your spec.

```
$ for f in folder-with-files/*; do echo "FILE: " $f; tail -2 $f; done > big.csv
```

Result:

```
$ cat big.csv
FILE:  folder-with-files/a
4
5
FILE:  folder-with-files/b
14
15
FILE:  folder-with-files/c
24
25
FILE:  folder-with-files/d
34
35
FILE:  folder-with-files/e
44
45
```

Comment: I’ll give it a whirl this weekend. Thanks!